# Two primes of the form $\ 10^p+333667$

Tags: number-theory

Consider the numbers of the form:

$10^n+333667$.

With the help of Pfgw I found that $10^n+333667$, up to $n=19000$, is prime for n: $3,4,7,9,18,43,144,1173,1192,1923,10443,14520,16623$.

Among these values of n leading to a prime there are only two which are primes themselves: $7$ and $43$.

Is there any mathematical reason why when $n$ is prime, that is in the cases $n=7,43$:

$10^7+333667\equiv 42\pmod {2375}$

$10^{43}+333667\equiv 42\pmod {2375}$?

remember that 
$10^7+333667$

$10^{43}+333667$ are both primes.

It is also quite surprising that $\frac{10^7+333667-42}{2375}$ is a semi prime and so also $\frac{10^{43}+333667-42}{2375}$ is a semi-prime.

Comment: This seems quite arbitrary.  $10^7\equiv 10 ^{43}\equiv 15  \pmod {95}$.  So what?

Comment: @lulu i changed with mod 2375

Comment: The difference is $10^{43}-10^7=10^7(10^{36}-1)$.  The first factor is a multiple of $125$.  The second is a multiple of $10^{18}-1$, which by Fermat's Little Theorem is a multiple of $19$.

Comment: So?  still arbitrary.  $10^{43}-10^7$ is divisible by a lot of numbers.

Comment: @lulu you don't understand...i give up

Answer (score 1):

Notice that $10^n+333667\equiv42\pmod{125}$ for all $n>2$. so this bit doesn't give you any information.

Now $42-333667\equiv-4\equiv15\pmod{19}$, so you want to find solutions for

$$
10^n\equiv15\pmod{19}
$$

Notice that 10 is a generator mod 19 and $10^7\equiv 15\pmod{19}$, so $n$ must of the form $7+\varphi(19)k=7+18k$.

So any number of this form will verify your equation.

Now, you may want to study what happens to $N=10^{7+18k}+333667$ when $7+18k$ is prime or, conversely, $7+18k$ when $N$ is prime. You may want to use something like [Pari/GP](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/) for that.